# What is OR EQUAL

Tags: objective-c, c

```
dataUpdated |= [backgroundApplicationData downloadLinks];
```

What does this Or/Equal mean? Never seen it before.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's bitwise OR, but condensed like `+=`.

It's equivalent to `dataUpdated = dateUpdated | [backgroundApplicationData downloadLinks];`

Here's a list of the bitwise operators: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Operators_and_Expressions#Compound_Bitwise_Operators

Comment: @FooBah - yep, for real it's in many languages (I can't think of a popular language that doesn't have equivalent operators). I used an obj-c link since the question used obj-c code.

Comment: Oh yeah - it just looks  weird and confusing. Although, I regularly use +=.